# How to search for a word in file contents?

Tags: php, url, search

I am new to php, just got stuck with something could be even simple...
Anyway, I want to do some action if the value from the "url" has a word "Success" in it:

`$c = file_get_content($url)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Always* search through the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
if (strpos($c, "string") !== false) {
  // "string" is in $c
} else {
  // "string" isn't in $c
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use stripos() for case-insensitive, and strpos() for case-sensitive search.